# Did Microsoft discontinue Azure Access Control Services

Tags: azure, active-directory, adfs

I am unable to find how Windows Azure Access Control Services can be accessed in the new Azure dashboard.  I assume that it has been discontinued.

When I search for news on the topic, there is a blog post [dating to 2015 which proclaim Azure AD as the future path for ACS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory/).

However, I do not actually see parity with what was capable with ACS and what is currently in Azure AD.  Basically, it seems like if you want to achieve federation-as-a-service in the cloud with Azure you have no options now; you *have* to use a VM with AD FS.

Is this correct?  Are there any known plans from Microsoft to bring back federation-as-a-service in Azure?

Comment: Odd that this got downvoted as Microsoft did not fully announce Azure ACS formal discontinuation until April: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/acs-access-control-service-namespace-creation-restriction/.  Azure AD B2C is supposed to replace it, but from what I've seen custom policies in Azure AD B2C is still in public preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom and requires extensive XML-based configuration vs. the very straight forward configuration of ACS.  Leaving these notes here for anyone that comes across this!

Answer (score 1):

yes, ACS is discuntinued.
you should look into AAD, AAD B2B and AAD B2C. the goal is to deliver a modern identity platform using these vehicles. if what you are looking for is not there yet, you can vote it up here
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory

Comment: I've spent quite a bit of time looking into B2B and B2C.  While they offer subsets of functionality between ACS, they are ultimately a bit disjointed whereas ACS was more cohesive.  It seemed like earlier Microsoft direction with Azure AD was that they would provide comparable ACS features, it seems like even with B2B and B2C, you can't achieve federation without AD FS now.